# Can't update, apt-get -f install error "no space left on device"

Tags: apt, kernel, disk-usage

I have been using Ubuntu on my laptop for a while now but am not proficient in it. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron Laptop, Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4200 @ 2.00GHz × 2, 3GB memory.

The Software Updater crashes and updating from the Terminal gives back unmet dependencies. When I try `apt-get -f install` I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
...
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 201 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87,5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...
(Reading database ... 896154 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-112_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-112 (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-112_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 error creating directory `./usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-112/drivers/isdn/act2000': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
   dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 error creating directory `./usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic/include/config/lp8788': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-112_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`df -h` shows the `/boot` partition is 84% full

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,5G  4,0K  1,5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           298M  1,4M  296M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        41G   20G   19G  52% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,5G   24M  1,5G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   56K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5       945M  734M  147M  84% /boot
/dev/sda7        12G  8,1G  3,0G  74% /usr
/dev/sda3       178G  152G   26G  86% /media/andrei/OS
```

Comment: The main message is `No space left on device`. Please update your question with output of `df -h`.

Comment: Found the right thread with cleaning up boot partition, will follow, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Read the error messages carefully - they do not indicate a /boot partition problem...though `df` does indeed indicate that problem too. You have *two* problems. After cleaning out /boot, check your inodes (`df -i`). Kernel headers absorb a lot of inodes; you might need to uninstall one or more old kernel header packages.